# External microphone not picking up signal on Dell Inspiron

Tags: windows, audio, microphone, dell-inspiron

On a new Dell Inspiron laptop running Windows 11, when I first insert an audio cable (external microphone) into the jack port, a prompt came up from what looked like a third party software that asked whether I should treat that device as headphones or a microphone. I  selected microphone and also ticked the "do not show this again" option by mistake.

There seems however to be no (good) signal picked up when speaking into the external mic. I wanted to get that menu back to see if other options existed that I could try, such as "line in", which on second thought was what I needed.

But the Dell control panel includes nothing of the sort, and installing / updating the Realtek audio driver didn't change the situation. Also installing the Waves Maxx application (bundled with Dell installations) didn't show any useful settings.

In the Windows settings, "jack mic Realtek" appears when the cable is plugged in, which should be fine, but again, no signal is picked up.

The microphone works fine on other devices, so this is likely a driver/software issue, or perhaps a problem with this new laptop's jack port.

Any suggestions for what else can be tried would be appreciated!

Comment: In the end that option to select mic/line-in was available in the MyDell app, which I could install separately. However, even selecting line-in doesn't give a good quality input so I'm guessing something is wrong with that jack port.